# Relation between C-rate and power of a battery

Tags: power, batteries

I'm a non-engineer, but I need to understand the function of a battery. I hope you can help me!

For example, I have two bulk storages.

1. 5MW (power) 5 MWh (capacity)
2. 5MW/10 MWh

So the definition of the c-rate is: A C-rate is a measure of the rate at which a battery is discharged relative to its maximum capacity. A 1C rate means that the discharge current will discharge the entire battery in 1 hour.

So for the second storage, a 1C shouldn't be possible? Because it is not possible to discharge the whole capacity in one hour because of the power? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? If it is real, please post links to datasheets if possible, there may be more information that may help. They sound like something in a submarine; 5 Mega Watts!

Comment: It is more or less theoretical. As you can see here http://www.younicos.com/en/home, these batteries are used for the electricity market.

Comment: C rate is a metric of bare cells, not a gigantic 5MW power bank.  The site you link calls it "rated power" (for the facility as a whole) which must include electronics, wiring and such.

Comment: 1C should be possible, but running at a lower rate relative to capacity will give higher cycle life so the cells don't need to be replaced as often.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @MattB. So cycle vs. dod [Link](http://c34.org/bbs/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=5602.0;attach=1792;image) depends also on the discharge rate, right? 100 % DOD with 1C results in a higher capacity fade, than a 100% DOD with 0,25C?

Comment: Yes, I would expect so.  Temperature matters also, as does the chemistry used.  A document from the Younicos site says they used lithium-manganese-oxide cells, not deep cycle lead acid as in your above link.  http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/types_of_lithium_ion  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_battery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right (provided that the 5 MW spec is the upper limit of the power).

In the first case you have an exactly 1C-rated storage, whereas in the second case it's 0.5C. Note that putting two 1C-rated storages in parallel will still provide 1C maximum discharge rate.

Comment: "Note that putting two 1C storages in parallel will still provide 1C discharge rate" seems counter-intuitive. Can you explain that, or give a reference?

Comment: @gbulmer if you have two storages of 5MW/5MWh, you'll get 10MW(5+5)/10MWh(also 5+5). Therefore the discharge rate doesn't change. I'd say it's more of an intrinsic property.

Comment: are you saying by doubling the output power and the capacity at the same time, the "1C" ratio still remains?

Comment: @KyranF it's more appropriate to say that two batteries in parallel will have both double maximum current (ideally) and double capacity. But then of course you need protection diodes and the non-ideality that follows.

Comment: Ah ha! I see the point; power and capacity increase, but discharge rate is constant. Thanks.