# What is the meaning of 25C?

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, batteries

I have a lipo battery of 11.1V,3s,5200mAH. What is the meaning of the 25C discharge current? How much current does it indicate? How do you interpret it?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178459/lead-acid-battery-charge-c-20ah http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/134247/relation-between-c-rate-and-power-of-a-battery

Comment: Anyone know what the "3s" refers to in "11.1 V, 3s, 5200 mAh"?

Comment: 3s i believe is how many cells are inside the battery. So in this case, it means 3 cells.

Comment: A battery that is described as xsyp has x cells in series in each string, and y strings of cells in parallel, for a total of xy cells. If x or y is one, then the 1s or 1p is usually omitted.

Answer (score 6):

C is the rated capacity, which in your case is 5.2Ah. We conventionally drop the hour unit to calculate the current in Cs.

25C is therefore a current of 130A.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know lipo batteries can give that much current.

Comment: Yes, they can, one of the reasons for respect when using them. Don't think that your battery can deliver 130A for 1/25th of an hour = 2.4 minutes, the capacity drops as the discharge rate increases. That 25C rating is what it can deliver, and without damaging itself.

Comment: A side question if I may, so it means that if I want to use another power source to power up a quadcopter, I need roughly 100A to power it up correctly?

Comment: If your quadcopter needs 100A, then it needs 100A. What relevance do you think that has to this question????????

Comment: just because your battery can deliver 130A, that doesn't mean your  quadcopter acutally draws 130A, it probably is much less. You can fly longer than 2.4 min, can't you? You only have a upper boundary, that 130A is going to work, we know nothing about the lower limit.

Comment: Oh i get it now, that's the maximum discharge rate. Thank  you so much!

Comment: @HenryLachica On this SE it is not recommended to accept an answer so quickly, as it discourages others to contribute to the discussion - the bonus is already gone, after all. 24 hours is a reasonable lower bound.

Comment: I found a 16Ah 10C (LiPo) battery to power a ~8A motor, for how much time I can power that motor? 2 hours or 20 hours?